# Unable to post Facebook messages(including text and images ) on Android M(MarshMallow) device with Facebook app exit in device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile

Unable to post Facebook messages(including text and images ) on Android M(MarshMallow) device with Facebook app exit in device.

Currently we are using  minSdkVersion 15 , targetSdkVersion 23 and facebook android sdk 4.7.0 version.

We are able to Share the Story with comments upto the Android Lollipap version in both Web View ( Facebook App not installed in mobile device )
and Native View ( Facebook App already installed in mobile device)

We have given the public_profile and user_friends permission while sharing.

Below is code :

```
CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);        
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
        // Return the facebook share dialog callback
        shareDialog.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                getLayout(layoutId);
                Toast.makeText(this,"You shared this post to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                getLayout(layoutId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                Log.e("Exception in callback", "Callback exception");
            }
        });
        // Initialize the LoginManager instance
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // On Successful Login share the story along with text and images
                        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareOpenGraphContent.class)) {
                            if(sharePhotoList!=null && !(sharePhotoList.isEmpty()))
                            {
                                if(sharePhotoList.size() > 1) {
                                    object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                                            .putString("fb:app_id", facebookAppId)
                                            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
                                            .putString("og:title", titleTxt)
                                            .putString("og:description", descriptionTxt)
                                            .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
                                            .build();

                                    action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                                            .setActionType("books.reads")
                                            .putPhotoArrayList("image", sharePhotoList)
                                            .putObject("book", object)
                                            .build();
                                }else
                                {
                                    object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                                            .putString("fb:app_id", facebookAppId)
                                            .putString("og:type", "books.book")
                                            .putString("og:title", titleTxt)
                                            .putString("og:description", descriptionTxt)
                                            .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
                                            .putPhoto("og:image", sharePhotoList.get(0))
                                            .build();

                                    action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                                            .setActionType("books.reads")
                                            .putObject("book", object)
                                            .build();
                                }
                            }else
                            {
                                object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                                        .putString("fb:app_id", facebookAppId)
                                        .putString("og:type", "books.book")
                                        .putString("og:title", titleTxt)
                                        .putString("og:description", descriptionTxt)
                                        .putString("books:isbn", "0-553-57340-3")
                                        .build();
                                action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                                        .setActionType("books.reads")
                                        .putObject("book", object)
                                        .build();
                            }
                            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                                    .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
                                    .setAction(action)
                                    .build();
                            shareDialog.show(content);
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // On cancel return to the page
                        getLayout(layoutId);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error){
                     Log.e("Exception in Login", "Login exception");
                    }
                });
        return mCallbackManager;
        }
```

When we Share the story on Android M device , we are able to send via Web View ( Facebook App not installed in mobile device )
but when we post the story in Native View ( Facebook App installed in mobile device ) then, its failing and showing continuously loading screen.
After some time it will disconnect from Facebook.

Is any one facing same problem with Facebook sharing in Android M?
Does I need to change in permission for this issue ?
Please provide me the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We are tracking some issues regarding Facebook Dialogs misbehaving based on the permissions (or lack of) giving to the native Facebook app. You can subscribe to the bug we are tracking [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/422183831323981/).

Comment: Thanks ,I have subscribed this bug for your further tracking.Please let me know is there any workaround for this issue.